# How to return a web color constant from a color stored as a string?

Tags: delphi

```
//clWebSnow = $FAFAFF; defined in Graphics.pas
Listbox1.Items.Add( ColorToString( clRed ) );
Listbox1.Items.Add( ColorToString( clWebSnow ) );
```

How can you return "WebSnow" as a string to show the color as a color constant as WebSnow?

All i can seem to get is '$FAFAFF' as a string with webcolors stored as a string while the StandardColors and ExtendedColors return the color constant values.

Example:
clRed displays as Red in the listbox and displays as Red in the Label caption.
clWebSnow displays as '$FAFAFF' in the listbox and displays as $FAFAFF in the label caption.

Bill

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at [RGBToWebColorName](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/GraphUtil.RGBToWebColorName) in [GraphUtil](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/GraphUtil).

```
  Label1.Caption := RGBToWebColorName(clWebSnow); // returns "clWebSnow"
```

Comment: If you're interested, there are some more conversion and utility methods in GraphUtils.pas for web and RGB colours.

Comment: Online documentation for GrahUtil is available here.

http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/GraphUtil.html

Comment: Ah, documentation. The developer's last resort. :)  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

ColorToString looks color names up with an IntToIdent map using the const array "Colors" defined in Graphics.pas.  Probably the only way to get around this is to use a custom Graphics.pas in which you've added new entries to the array.